# How to delete columns 1,2,7 of this numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this numpy ndarray `nd`.

```
[['BO' '05-02-2009' 1.0718954248366013 1.1620915032679742
  1.0045751633986928 1.1130718954248366 272564]
 ['BO' '06-02-2009' 1.1339869281045751 1.1941176470588235
  1.1189542483660129 1.1718954248366011 189758]
 ['BO' '09-02-2009' 1.1705882352941177 1.1725490196078432
  1.1320261437908496 1.1601307189542482 109528]]
```

I want to delete the first column, 2nd column and last column.

`nd` with the deleted columns will look like this;

```
 [[1.0718954248366013 1.1620915032679742
  1.0045751633986928 1.1130718954248366 ]
 [1.1339869281045751 1.1941176470588235
  1.1189542483660129 1.1718954248366011 ]
 [1.1705882352941177 1.1725490196078432
  1.1320261437908496 1.1601307189542482 ]]
```

I tried to delete the column using the code below;

```
import numpy as np
nd = np.delete(nd, 1, 0)  # delete column 1
nd = np.delete(nd, 1, 1)  # delete column 2
nd = np.delete(nd, 1, 4)  # delete column 7
```

However, the columns remain. How can the columns be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably have the [order of arguments](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) wrong. The axis (1) comes second.

It would also be easier to do it all in one swoop: `nd = np.delete(nd, [0,1,6], 1)`.

Comment: I'm still at a loss with your answer. Do you mind providing more details?

Comment: I deleted my answer as you happen to post it 30 second before me.